# python deduplicate if item repeats in anywhere between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that contains email contacts. In two Columns, some emails are repeated. for example

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0Y6.jpg)

I need to be able to go through the list and create a new output with the combined columns **Email List A** and **Email list B** only with their unique values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('Emails.csv', 'r') as infile, open('uniqueEmails.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    uniqueEmails= []
    results = csv.DictReader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['Email']) 
    for result in results:
        uniqueEmailA = result.get('Email List A')
        uniqueEmailB= result.get('Email List B')
        if uniqueEmailA in uniqueEmailB:
        continue 
writer.writerow([ result.get('Email'),uniqueEmailA]) 
uniqueEmailA.append(uniqueEmailB)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).